# Access SimpleXML node value as string

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an object called $picasa_feed like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [guid] => https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/base/user/0000000000000000/albumid/0000000000000000?alt=rss&hl=en_US
    [pubDate] => Fri, 12 Dec 2008 20:00:00 +0000
    [category] => http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007#album
    [title] => My Pictures
    [description] => ...
    [link] => https://picasaweb.google.com/0000000000000000/MyAlbum
    [author] => Me
)
```

I want to take put a property value into an element of an associative array:

```
$data_to_save['title'] = $picasa_feed->title;
```

When I do that the value of $data_to_save is

```
Array
(
    [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => My Pictures
        )
}
```

What I want is

```
Array
(
    [title] => My Pictures
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to invoke the SimpleXMLElement's magic `__toString` method by casting it to string. Try: `$data_to_save['title'] = (string)$picasa_feed->title;`

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  That did it!  Is it always necessary to access object properties that way, or is it something particular to SimpleXMLElement?

Comment: Accessing the property of an object will yield whatever data type that property has.  Due to the nested nature of XML, the SimpleXMLElement is just a collection of more SimpleXMLElements (nodes / children / [..]).

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to string:

```
$data_to_save['title'] = (string) $picasa_feed->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$data_to_save['title'] = (string) $picasa_feed->title;
```