# Get value from PHP SimpleXMLElement object ([0] => value)

Tags: php, simplexml

I have this code, and I can't get the real value from this structure
Prices/Price or Prices/RoomPrice because always in print_r or var_dump displays
    SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 19 )

This is my code:

```
$prices = $boardPlan->Prices->Price; 
var_dump($prices);
//VAR_DUMP of this displays SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 19 )
//Similar is for these codes:
print_r($prices[0]);
print_r($prices{0});
```

I need to get only the value "19".

Also, If I add this code:

```
$prices = $boardPlan->Prices->Price->{0}; 
var_dump($prices);
//VAR_DUMP displays nothing
```

This is my XML String:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <soap:Body>
              <RoomRateListUpdRequest>
                 <RoomRateListUpdRQ Language="es">
                    <Login User="xxx" Password="password" HotelCode="1" />
                    <RoomRateListUpd>
                       <Contracts>
                          <Contract id="547">
                             <Rates>
                                <Rate Id="1479" DateFrom="2011-01-01" DateTo="2011-01-02">
                                   <Rooms>
                                      <Room RoomTypeID="257">
                                         <BoardPlans>
                                            <BoardPlan Id="2">
                                               <Prices>
                                                  <Price>19</Price>
                                                  <RoomPrice>0</RoomPrice>
                                                  <ChildrenPrices>
                                                     <ChildA>
                                                        <ChildPriceA1>99</ChildPriceA1>
                                                        <ChildPriceA2>100</ChildPriceA2>
                                                        <ChildPriceA3>100</ChildPriceA3>
                                                        <ChildPriceA4>100</ChildPriceA4>
                                                        <ChildPriceA5>100</ChildPriceA5>
                                                     </ChildA>
                                                     <ChildB>
                                                        <ChildPriceB1>50</ChildPriceB1>
                                                        <ChildPriceB2>50</ChildPriceB2>
                                                        <ChildPriceB3>50</ChildPriceB3>
                                                        <ChildPriceB4>50</ChildPriceB4>
                                                        <ChildPriceB5>50</ChildPriceB5>
                                                     </ChildB>
                                                  </ChildrenPrices>
                                                  <AditionalAdultPrices>
                                                     <AditionalPrice1>10</AditionalPrice1>
                                                     <AditionalPrice2>10</AditionalPrice2>
                                                     <AditionalPrice3>10</AditionalPrice3>
                                                     <AditionalPrice4>10</AditionalPrice4>
                                                     <AditionalPrice5>10</AditionalPrice5>
                                                     <AditionalPrice6>10</AditionalPrice6>
                                                     <AditionalPrice7>10</AditionalPrice7>
                                                     <AditionalPrice8>10</AditionalPrice8>
                                                  </AditionalAdultPrices>
                                               </Prices>
                                            </BoardPlan>
                                         </BoardPlans>
                                      </Room>
                                   </Rooms>
                                </Rate>
                             </Rates>
                          </Contract>
                       </Contracts>
                    </RoomRateListUpd>
                 </RoomRateListUpdRQ>
              </RoomRateListUpdRequest>
           </soap:Body>
         </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You might be looking for [__toString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php)

Comment: Yes! sure!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: FYI, if you simply use `echo` instead of `var_dump()`, I think that gets called automatically behind the scenes.

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862977/access-simplexml-node-value-as-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867575/get-value-from-simplexmlelement-object)